# Does the Aura of the Road of Blood affect blood magic rolls?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-dark-ages

At the Dark Ages Vampire V20, the Assamite's Road of Blood have the following aura description:

> **Aura:** Resolve. A follower of the Road of Blood takes his task seriously and is dedicated to following through. The aura modifier affects Willpower rolls.

The Storyteller is using the rules of ***The Blood and the Will*** of the *Rites of Blood* supplement, my character has Dur-An-Ki so it doesn't make any difference now, but I might be able to learn something else in the future, then I kept it open to all blood magics following this rule.

My character (an assamite sorcerer) reached the 8th step on his Road of Blood and has a -1 difficulty modifier on his aura. Does that modifier apply to his Dur-An-Ki activation rolls?

This question have splitted the party in half, some think it should only affect social situations and others use the argument that auras can even be used on and against disciplines if the theme allows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question! Let's start with checking what the rulebook says.
Dark Ages vampire, page 113:

> A practitioner of a Road possesses a certain aura, a personal
>   bearing, a palpable force of presence that embodies the
>   Road’s ethos. For characters high on their Roads, this gives
>   them a reduced difficulty on rolls due to their confidence
>   and grace in these situations.

For the basic Aura description this is clear. Your aura is a permanent bearing. It can lower rolls because of confidence and/or grace (and/or experience) in certain situations.

> Aura modifiers definitely apply to relevant Social rolls.
>   However, with Storyteller discretion, a character’s aura
>   might affect any roll with which her character’s bearing
>   should give an advantage or disadvantage. For example,
>   a character on the Road of Kings might get her aura
>   modifier on Willpower rolls to resist forced subordination.
>   As a Storyteller, favor allowing dramatically appropriate
>   benefits from auras. After all, maintaining a high Road
>   score can be a challenge; the player most certainly earned
>   the benefits

I assume it's this part that started the discussion. So yes, aura bearing can indeed affect disciplines, a Road of Kings character would gain it for resisting majesty from someone who is a "lesser" to them.

But let's transfer the example: Your aura makes it easier to stay on the path you set for yourself and you're not easy to sway. Which means every time you have to roll in order not to be swayed or influenced - your modifier applies. That's mostly Willpower rolls, of course, but your GM could decide to let it apply for other rolls as well. Like a Dominate "Stop!" if you are set on continuing.

Does this mean you get to modify every single willpower roll you make, including blood magic? Definitely not. The situation still has to fit and "I really want to use a spell so this is dedication!" is not an excuse.
Now ...if you really NEED to use a spell because it's vital to your goals or if you'd normally get a negative modifier for distraction ...That's a different story altogether. In such a case your GM could allow it for your spell as well.

But you do not get the modifier for all your willpower rolls and your social-primary Ventrue does not get the modifier for each time he tries talking to somebody.